# Extract data from observable in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having some trouble in understanding how to use observables in Angular 2 correctly. I have the following query that I use:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/admin/is-admin.json', options)
  .map(res => res)
  .catch(this.handleError);   }
```

The API call returns a boolean value true or undefined, but I somehow am not able to return this value from my function. At the moment it returns an object, where I want it to directly return the boolean value. When I change my map line to:

```
  .map(res => JSON.parse(res))
```

I get a JSON parse error, if I change it to:

```
  .map(res => res.data)
```

I get an error that data doesn't exist on the response object. Does anybody know what I should do? The answer is probably quite basic, but I have been looking for it for quite some time now...

Comment: try `.map(res => res.json())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following by getting the text value of the response payload:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/admin/is-admin.json', options)
  .map(res => { // <-----
    let responsePayload = res.text();
    return (responsePayload != null) ? Boolean(res.text()) : responsePayload;
   }))
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

You could also try to call the `json` method:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/admin/is-admin.json', options)
  .map(res => res.json()) // <-----
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the observable

```
getData() {
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/admin/is-admin.json', options)
    .map(res => res.json)
    .catch(this.handleError);   
}

otherFunc() {
  this.getData().subscribe(val => this.data = val);
}
```

or

```
<div>
  {{data | json}}
</div>
```

constructor() {
      this.data = getData();
    }